# Issue with the 'strong' property

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to learn Objective-C. So I've just implemented a ProfileViewController and here is my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;//strong is not colored by XCode

@end
```

But I have the following error with the `@property` line and I'm completely stuck with it :

```
No 'assign', 'retain' or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed
Default property 'assign' not appropriate for non-gc object
```

And in my `ProfileViewController.m` I have the following warning : `Property 'scrollView' needs`setScrollView `need to be defined`

```
Developer Information:

  Version:  4.1 (4B110)
  Location: /Developer
  Applications:
  Xcode:    4.1 (516)
  Instruments:  4.1 (4138)
  Dashcode: 3.0.2 (336)
  SDKs:
  Mac OS X:
  10,6: (10J567)
  10,7: (11A511a)
  iPhone OS:
  4,3:  (8H7)
  iPhone Simulator:
  4,3:  (8H7)
```

Comment: It's possible you have an invisible character that got inserted into the file you're working on.  Re-define the property.

Comment: Update your version of Xcode. I don't believe 4.1 supports ARC, which introduced the strong keyword.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strong properties are a feature of ARC (automatic reference counting) which is available since Xcode 4.2 (LLVM compiler 3.0), compare https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I've now Xcode 4.6.2! But I'm getting the following error : 'Expected a property attribute before strong'. I've seen that it might be the compiler which can be out of date. But I'm very new to XCode and I'm a little confused about that. Thanks !

Comment: @Reveclaire: Probably you have to convert the project to ARC: Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using ARC ? Did you tick-marked the checkbox 'use automatic reference counting' while creating the project ? If you use older version of XCode, then you will not get such options as it does not support ARC. In that case, either update your xcode or continue without ARC using manual memory management and keywords such as 'assign/nonassign' instead of 'strong/weak' ...